# Как пропорционально уменьшить все элементы на странице?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Нужно пропорционально уменьшить размер всех элементов на странице, шрифтов, отступов и т.д., чтобы новая страница выглядела как старая при 90% масштабе. Есть ли какое-то готовое решение этой задачи?

Answer (score 2):

Используйте css-свойство `zoom`:

```
body {
    zoom : 90%;
}
```

Либо можете устанавливать его динамически, с помощь jQuery:

```
$('body').css('zoom', '90%');
```